# Bad access after releasing image reference

Tags: ios, pointers, uiimage, cgimageref

I got bad access error when trying to get the reference image back from UIImage:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = mat2CGImageRef(mat);
_documentUIImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

After that if I want to get the CGImageRef from the uiimage I got bad access error!

```
return _documentUIImage.CGImage
```

I believe that the variable UIImage should have different address than the image ref.. so why after releasing it I got bad access?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the `UIImage` `initWithCGImage` simply wraps the `CGImage` and does not duplicate the data.

In any case the method should retain the `CGImage` so the `CGImageRelease` should not be responsible for the exception.

This should lead to conclusion that the `CGImageRelease` must be removed in your case as the `mat2CGImageRef` does not retain it. What does this function do anyway? Try to follow the rule that only functions and methods that contain words such as "create", "copy", "alloc" produce the result which needs to be released.

Comment: Thanks for you reply
After scanning the code .. the CGImageRef was released in another place as well .. so I kept just one release and it works fine now
best regards